# jquery resize function not working the way I'd expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I have a container element that has an `<img>` tag in it. The width of the image is 100%, and the height is `auto`. Overflow on the container is set to `hidden` and it also has a `max-height` and `min-height`. The idea is to have the image determine the height of the container, within the max and min breakpoints.

So, the container has a relative height. In order to have a fluid transition, I reset the height on the `resize` event (for a complicated reason, the `img` itself does not set the height, rather it is calculated and then changed via javascript). This works fine, and when I resize the window, it all works right.

But some of the logic that is in the resize event I want to run on the load event as well. So, I thought I would just call resize within load, like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```

But, this did not work. With this code, if I manually resize the window even just one pixel, the containing element will scale properly (it's about a `200px` difference from the height calculated on load to the reset, properly scaled height).

Apparently, my understanding of how this works is wrong. I have called other events before like this to fire the event and trigger something else. How can I accomplish what I want?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/zpkxY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what the problem was. I changed my approach and found a different solution that does not need the `resize` event to be called on `load`.

Answer (score 1):

Still wondering what's actually being achieved by re-sizing the window but another way to trigger `resize` would be :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(this).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .ready instead of .load

```
$(window).ready(function);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2Xtr/2/)

Comment: I don't think that this is a solution in this case. because load event actually firing after the ready event.(Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)